# Why can't I execute Wubi in Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, executable, windows-8

I tried executing Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop but it won't execute. I tried downloading it again, executing as administrator etc but nothing happens. I think something is wrong with my laptop. I'm using windows 8 consumer preview.

Comment: Look in the log file in the `%TEMP%` directory. That might have some clues. If no logfile, do you have python installed? Wubi.exe has been run on Windows 8 so this is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Try to install and run it Windows7 compatibility mode.

Comment: One question, which build is it? On my old laptop (Win 8 Consumer Preview Build 8250), it worked perfectly fine. Did you get wubi for 12.04 or 12.10? Only 12.10 worked on mine, so if you were trying to install 12.04 then it would probably not work.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Windows release WUBI is compatible with is **Windows 7**. It may work on Windows 8 previews/betas, then again, it may not. It's unsupported, so you're not likely to get much help trying to make it work, sorry.

Comment: The best way for it to be supported on Windows8 is for users to try it and report the issues, and then for us to figure out what went wrong. It worked when I used it (in a VM) and I've seen a number of posts that go beyond 'nothing happening' so it'd be good to see why it works on some and not on others (and whether these fail cases are the same as the fail cases on Windows 7). I, for one, am prepared to help and I'm sure others are as well.